# Angular 2 - how to create a global service that I only need to load once

Tags: angular

What would you suggest is the easiest method for achieving this. I want to create a global service or directive that checks the screen width, so I could use it like this

`<div *ngIf="screenSize < 1024">mobile element</div>`.

What would be the best approach?

Comment: Have a look at the [@angular/flex-layout](https://github.com/angular/flex-layout) project.  It can handle all this for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Pure CSS**

I suggest `@media` queries

```
@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .mobile-element {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

and the HTML

```
<div class="mobile-element">mobile element</div>
```

**With angular service**

if you must do it in Angular or you are trying to prevent elements from loading  you could make a global service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class ScreenSizeService{
      innerHeight = (window.innerHeight);
      innerWidth = (window.innerWidth);
}
```

Inject it in the `app.module.ts` under `providers` (so it only loads once)

Inject the service into your component:

```
import {ScreenSizeService} from 'path_to_service';
...
export class SomeComponent{
  constructor(public screenSizeService: ScreenSizeService){} //injecting the service
}
```

Then use it in the HTML

```
<div *ngIf="screenSizeService.innerWidth < 1024">mobile element</div>
```

Comment: Looks good, but doesn't work for me. I get this error "[Angular] Identifier 'ScreenSizeService' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member". Do I need to import it into the component as well?

Comment: you need to inject the service into the component using it added some details to help you

Comment: With the current approach I still need to inject the service for each component. The first goal was to have a global service that would work for all components without making any imports, not sure if it's even possible. Anyway as this kind of solves my problem, I will accept your answer after you accept the edits :)